# How to set up a mixed partitioned sd card (part adoptable, part removable) on android Marshmallow on an HTC One M8?

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, partition, mixed

I followed this guide:

http://blog.sam.liddicott.com/2016/02/android-6-semi-adopted-storage.html?showComment=1499351433951#c5567046039565096367

I did everything as explained as this was also exactly the solution I was looking for, however, there is a problem using the partitions. I tried it with a htc One M8.

The partition succeeded, I typed:

adb shell sm partition disk:179,32 mixed 60

gives me two corrupted sd card entries in the storage menu on my android device, one listed under internal storage, one under removable storage. Great, so now I want to set up each partition... and there it goes wrong: when I click set up partition in the storage menu of android, it formats the whole sd card as either internal or removable, no matter from which partition I start the process. Damn, gone partitions. Any solutions? Can I maybe format each partition separately from the adb terminal?

When I type:

```
platform-tools>adb shell sm list-volumes all
```

I get:

> private:179,35 unmountable null
>   private mounted null
>   public:179,33 unmountable null
>   emulated mounted null

Answer (score 1):

This option is explicitly disabled by HTC. Only rooting first would allow for this proces to work.